# Extensions not working and options not showings Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm running the latest version of Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (16.6.2) and there seems to be some problem with extensions.

I cannot browse extensions in the Extension Manager, it just tells me "There are no configured extension galleries."

When I have downloaded the vsix files for extensions directly from the VS Marketplace and installed them, while the extensions do show as installed in the Manager, they do not work.

As an example [Trailing Whitespace Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TrailingWhitespaceVisualizer), after installing it, the options for the extension do not show up in the Options dialog, also in this case. A get an Object Reference not set to instance of an object dialog whenever I click Save.

I've tried a bunch of extensions and none of them show up in the Options dialog. The ones that include Roslyn analysers are the only ones that work - although I cannot change their settings.

I completely uninstalled everything last week and started again as a fresh install and it made no difference. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: [log VS2019 activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) and check the log file for errors

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. Has anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this yet?

Comment: @ShrapNull afraid not. I got a new computer - not just because of this :)